# Python 3 writelines (a bytes-like object is required, not 'str')

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am converting python 2 to python 3 scripts, but I am getting error when I execute the python 3 script

Error: "msg": "Write SQL ===> Problem writing sql script /tmp/ansible_xscchanlfy.sql [a bytes-like object is required, not 'str']",

The issue seems to be in the following code, but I cannot figure it out.

```
def write_script(filename, content, owner='root'):
    with open(filename, 'ab') as out_file:
        if type(content) == list:
            out_file.writelines(list([x + '\n' for x in content]))
        else:
            out_file.write(content.encode('utf-8'))            
    owner_pw = pwd.getpwnam(owner)
    os.chown(filename, owner_pw.pw_uid, owner_pw.pw_gid)
    os.chmod(filename, stat.S_IRWXU)
```

Below is the rest of the code, where I call the function.

```
if runmode == 'sql':
            # Prepare execution string
            filename = os.path.join(args['tmpdir'], make_name(extension='sh'))
            sqlfile = os.path.join(args['tmpdir'], make_name(extension='sql'))
            if args['database']:
                content.append('db2 connect to %s > /dev/null 2>&1 &&' % args['database'])
            if args['separator'] == '':
                # db2_parameters = '-tvxf' if args['verbose'] else '-txf'   <== Remove the header from sql output
                db2_parameters = '-tvf' if args['verbose'] else '-tf'
            else:
               # db2_parameters = '-t%s -vxf' % args['separator'] if args['verbose'] else '-t%s -xf' % args['separator']
               db2_parameters = '-t%s -vf' % args['separator'] if args['verbose'] else '-t%s -f' % args['separator']
    
            # Write SQL script
            try:
                write_script(sqlfile, args['sql'], owner=args['instance'])
            except Exception as e:
                module.fail_json(msg='Write SQL ===> Problem writing sql script %s [%s]' % (sqlfile, e), **result)
    
            # Write SHELL script
            content.append('db2 %s %s' % (db2_parameters, sqlfile))
            cmd = ' '.join(content)
            result['cmd'] = cmd
            try:
                write_script(filename, cmd, owner=args['instance'])
            except Exception as e:
                module.fail_json(msg='Write SHELL  ===> Problem writing script %s [%s]' % (filename, e), **result)
    
            # RUN
            try:
                out = run(args['instance'], filename)
                os.remove(filename)
                os.remove(sqlfile)
            except Exception as e:
                module.fail_json(msg='RUN ==> Problem running script %s [%s]' % (filename, e), **result)
```

Comment: You opened the file in binary mode (`'ab'`), but are trying to write text to it. You probably want to open it in text mode instead.

Comment: I tried "at" and still getting same error.

Comment: I figured it out, using "a" fixed this issue." with open(filename, 'a') as out_file:"

Comment: @azadaawaraa also it is `a+` a plus not `a tee`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening file in `ab` mode, you need to open in `a` mode:

Try this:

```
with open(filename, 'a') as out_file:
```

or

```
with open(filename, 'a+') as out_file:
```

You can check this site for various modes:  https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

> With the mode specifiers above the file is open as a text file. In order to open a file as a binary file, a "b" character has to be included in the mode string. This additional "b" character can either be appended at the end of the string (thus making the following compound modes: "rb", "wb", "ab", "r+b", "w+b", "a+b") or be inserted between the letter and the "+" sign for the mixed modes ("rb+", "wb+", "ab+").